# настройка openServer

Tags: openserver, indexof

Всем привет!
В ходе настройки второго домена на OpenServer столкнулась с проблемой:
вместо отображения сайта - отображается index of с указанием всего содержимого сайта. 
как это можно поправить и в чем может быть проблема такого поведения?

Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description

Answer (score 1):

Была идентичная проблема. Переименовала главный файл на index.html и всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте что у вас присутствует файл, который должен открываться, и что он прописан в конфигурации Apache в опции DirectoryIndex